# Sharepoint 2013 - Setting item-level view permissions

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

I currently have a list that contains information regarding various users.

I want to give permissions to this list so that users can only view the information regarding them and nothing more. The methods I found while researching are by modifying view(Which doesn't seem ideal) or to filter the list which is impractical(Filtering the list by "created by" but since the users will only view their information and not create this option won't work). Anyone has any ideas or know what options there are?

Comment: You can create designer workflow on item created to change item level permission .

Comment: @BhaskarDhone that will be messy pretty soon. Just because you "can" does not mean you "should"

Answer (score 0):

How do you qualify if an item should be shown to a user? "Regarding them" needs a better explanation.

Item level permissions are a major pain to administer and should be avoided at (almost) all cost, unless you have some code that handles it.

If "regarding them" relates to a person/group field where "they" are listed as the only person or as one of several persons. then you can create a filter for that.

I suggest creating a page instead of using a list view, so you can send people to the page for "all items that relate to me". That way they can't easily switch to another list view of "All Items".  Manage your site navigation so that people easily find the "my items" page and make it hard for them to discover the "Site content" page and find the original list.

On the "my items" page, create a list view web part and filter it by the person column to be `equal to` and `[me]`. This works for person columns with multiple names as well as single names. If "regarding them" means the person is named in more than one person column, use OR to add more conditions to the filter.

Answer (score 0):

I did the modify view. that will solve your issue. In  modify view / Show items only when the following is true (section ) / put the username fiels is equal to [Me] . Every user when he will access the list, the list will show his data only. no need to change the view

Answer (score 0):

So your requirement is to set the item level permission, who are all creating an item in the list, they should view/edit only their items not any another items.

To achieve this requirement, just go to that list and list settings then Advanced Settings then change the Item-Level Permission to "Read items that were created by user" and create items and edit items that were created by the user"

So users can view only their items, not other items

[image]